# using downloadHandler and renderPlot on a static function simultaneously

Tags: r, shiny-server, shiny, shinydashboard

Please consider the following:

```
# createPlot takes in data, processes it and generates a plot using native plot()
    plotInput <- function(){       
     createPlot(data=data(),name=input$name)
    }

# I render it using
output$plot <- renderPlot({
    plotInput()
  }, height=700,width=850,res=100)

# and I download the pdf using
output$pdflink <- downloadHandler(
      filename <- "plot.pdf",
      content <- function(file){
        pdf("plot.pdf")
        print(plotInput())
        dev.off()
        file.copy("plot.pdf", file)
      }
  )
```

`createPlot` function has a `randomising` factor which fills in the empty values with a small random pseudocount. So, whenever this function is run, the points on the plot are not exactly the same thus the downloaded plot is a bit different than what I see on the interface. What can I do to come around this problem?

I've tried storing the output of `plotInput()` to a static variable and re-sue that variable for both rendering and exporting but it doesn't works like this.

```
mainPlot <- plotInput()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by generating a static pdf plot which I converted to a `.png` using `ImageMagick` and the rendered the converted image to the browser using the `renderImage`

```
# createPlot takes in data, processes it and generates a plot using native plot()
    plotInput <- reactive({       
     createPlot(data=data(),name=input$name)
    })

# I render it using
    output$plot <- renderImage({
     pdf("plot.pdf")
     print(plotInput())
     dev.off
# R wrapper for imagemagick
   im.convert('plot.pdf',output='plot.png',extra.opts="-density 250 -quality 100")
    list(src='plot.png',
     contentType='image/png',
     alt='emptyPlot')
   },deleteFile=FALSE)

# and I download the pdf using
    output$pdflink <- downloadHandler(
      filename <- "plot.pdf",
      content <- function(file){
        file.copy("plot.pdf", file)
      }
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of making `plotInput` a function, try making it into a "reactive".  Shiny should detect that when printing to file, there is no need to rerun the reactive if none of its inputs have changed, and therefore the renderPlot and the pdf should use the same plot

Comment: Thanks for your answer. `plotInput` earlier I had as a reactive function, but the problem was the during the downloading, no plot was being generated and thats still the case. So, if I convert `plotInput` to a reactive function, the `downloadHandler` returns a file but its empty. Plot is not generated.